# When I use exec to create table dynamicaly, ity gives an error

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

```
declare @a char(11),@b varchar(100)    
select @a = 'Actual_'+convert(char(4),datepart(year,getdate()))     
select @b='create table table_name ('+@a+' float null)'    
exec @b
```

and after last command I am getting message the name

> 'create table table_name (Actual_2015 float NULL)' is not valid identifier

Can somebody let me know, why?
I am working on ASE isql SYBASE 15

Answer (score 0):

Missing the brackets after exec,

```
declare @a char(11),@b varchar(100)    
select @a = 'Actual_'+convert(char(4),datepart(year,getdate()))     
select @b='create table table_name ('+@a+' float null)'    
exec (@b)
```